# List Generation in Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have a table of data with columns specifying different hold types (i.e., Credit, Forecast, Manual, Routing).

What I'd like is to generate a second table made of two columns:

- ID as the PK
- Values

The values column will identify the possible combinations from the above list. For example:

| ID | Values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | No Hold |
| 2 | Credit |
| 3 | Credit, Forecast |
| 4 | Credit, Manual |
| 4 | Credit, Routing |
| 5 | Credit, Forecast, Manual |
| 5 | Credit, Forecast, Routing |
| 5 | Credit, Manual, Routing |
| 6 | Forecast |
| 6 | Forecast, Manual |
| 6 | Forecast, Credit |

....

Can I have some help writing the correct M query to achieve this?

I've tried different configurations of Number.Factorial() after assigning numerical values to my text fields; I've tried List.Generate() and List.Numbers.

Comment: See the [answer of Alexis Olson](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Combinatorics-in-Power-Query-part1/bc-p/2221143/highlight/true#M3151) for an elegant method.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what the ID column represents (or what PK means) but this generates all combinations from the list formed by initial table Column1

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

Combinations = (SourceList as list, optional charactercount as list) as list =>
  //  horseyride adaptation of algo from Bill Szysz 2017
  // optional 2nd parameter  {1,2,3} to look for combinations with 1/2/3 members or omit for everything
  let AddIndex = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.FromList(List.Sort(SourceList)), "Index", 0, 1),
  ReverseIndeks = Table.AddIndexColumn(AddIndex, "RevIdx", Table.RowCount(AddIndex), -1),
  Lists = Table.AddColumn(ReverseIndeks, "lists", each List.Repeat(List.Combine({List.Repeat({[Column1]}, Number.Power(2,[RevIdx]-1)),List.Repeat(   {null}, Number.Power(2,[RevIdx]-1))}), Number.Power(2, [Index]))),
  ResultTable = Table.FromColumns(Lists[lists]),
  AllCombos = List.Sort(List.RemoveLastN(Table.AddColumn(ResultTable, "Custom", each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(Record.ToList(_)),", "))[Custom],1))
  in if charactercount= null then AllCombos else List.RemoveNulls(List.Transform(AllCombos, each if  List.ContainsAny(charactercount,{Text.Length(Text.Select(_,"-")&"-")}) then _ else null)),

CombinationOutput = Combinations(Source[Column1]),
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(CombinationOutput, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in #"Converted to Table"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method of generating combinations.

Add this custom function and name it `fnCombos`
*The reference has an explanation by the author of how it works*

```
//https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Community-Blog/Combinatorics-in-Power-Query-part1/bc-p/2221143/highlight/true#M3151
//  See answer of Alexis Olson

//fnCombos
//  combinations of all entries in a single list/column

(L as list) as list =>

let
    N = List.Count(L),
    Subsets =
        List.Transform(
            {0..Number.Power(2, N)-1},
            (i) => List.Transform(
                {0..N-1},
                (j) => if Number.Mod(Number.IntegerDivide(i, Number.Power(2, j)), 2) = 1
                    then L{j}
                    else null
                    )
        ),
  Concatenate = List.Transform(Subsets, each Text.Combine(List.RemoveNulls(_), ","))
in   
    Concatenate
```

You can then use the following to list the combinations:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45Wci5KTcksUYrViVZyyy9KTU4shnB8E/NKE3PAzKD80pLMvHQw2y8/L1UpNhYA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Column1 = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    ComboList = fnCombos(#"Changed Type"[Column1]),
    result = Table.FromColumns({List.RemoveFirstN(ComboList,1)}, type table[Column1=text])
in
    result
```

***Source Table***
[image]

***Results***
[image]